# SocketException (SocketException: No route to host (OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113)

Tags: flutter, flask

I have a Flask application running on my local machine, which I'm using as a backend for the Flutter application , but I'm getting this error

> ```
> SocketException (SocketException: No route to host (OS Error: No route to host, Errno = 113)
> ```

```
Future pix(String BackgroundImagePath, String originalImagePath) async {
      final uri = Uri.parse('http://my desktop address:5000').replace(queryParameters: {
        'original': originalImagePath,
        'background': BackgroundImagePath,
      });
    
      final response = await http.get(uri);
```

- The phone is connected to my laptop through a USB
- Both phone & Laptop    are on same WIFI
- I replaced `localhost` with my Ubuntu desktop IP address

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in your AndroidManifest.xml, inside the `<manifest>` tag.
I had the same problem and this solved it.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: it's already there

Comment: Is it in the *debug*, *main*, and *profile*'s `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Yes i made sure all have the permission

Answer (score 0):

run the app on your browser. it'll work fine